# Firebase Android - How to generate Facebook hash key. Package name and signing-certificate fingerprint do not match

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, facebook-login

I got the this error after signing in to facebook with firebase in my android app.

> Authentication failed: com.google.firebase.FirebaseExeption: An internal error has occured.
>
> Package name and signing-certificate fingerprint do not match.

I have a sha fingerprint in my firebase console and correct package name.
I have uploaded the app to Beta test, and I think I need a release sha key. But I don't know how to create it.

Any help ?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer.

I had to use this command:

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/YOUR/PATH/TO/KEYSTORE -list -v
```

and set the KEYSTORE path to my **.jdk** file in my project.

(The .jdk file is generated when creating a signed APK)

***Here is how I did it***

**Instructions:**

**First:** type this in the Terminal window(Mac) to generate debug.keystore

`keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64`

- I recomend not to chang the alias.
- Use "android" as passoword.
- Leave the debug.keystore file in the .android folder

**Second**: Before we can retrive the hash key for release we need to create a **.jdk** file. You can do this by Android Studio -> "Build"-tab -> "Generate signed APK". Or if you are developing a **Cordova app** you can create a **.jdk** file by typing this in your project directory:

`keytool -genkey -v -keystore my-release-key.jks -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000 -alias my-alias`

After creating the .jdk file you can create a **release hash** for facebook.

**Third**: type this in the terminal:

```
keytool -exportcert -alias YOUR_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS -keystore YOUR_RELEASE_KEY_PATH | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

And change **YOUR_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS** to what ever alias you gave the **.jdk file** and set the "**YOUR_RELEASE_KEY_PATH**" to the destination of the **.jdk file**. Some thing like this: *~/apps/myApp/myApp.jdk*

At the end it might look like this:

```
keytool -exportcert -alias myApp -keystore ~/apps/myApp/myApp.jdk | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

Answer (score 0):

**1. Terminal**

If you are using windows and you don't have the **openSSL**
Download Open SSL : https://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html

After installation, make sure you added path in `environment` variables.

Run the below command in terminal.

```
keytool -exportcert -alias <aliasName> -keystore <keystoreFilePath> | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

AliasName : Name of alias (Eg. Android, Release, Debug)
keystoreFilePath : Name of keystore if you are in same directory or full path

**2. Google Play Console**

if you already have your app on Play Store you can this:

1. Go to `Release Management`
2. select `App Signing` in `Release Management`
3. You can see SHA1 key in hex format `App signing certificate`.
4. Copy the SHA1 in hex format and convert it in to base64 format, you can use this link http://tomeko.net/online_tools/hex_to_base64.php to do that without the `SHA1:`  part of the hex.
5. Go to Facebook developer console and add the key(after convert to base 64) in the `settings —> basic –> key hashes`.

**3. Directly From App (Your app must be generated with debug or release with keystore file)**

Put below code in splash page or main page

```
PackageInfo info;
try {
    info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("com.you.name", PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
    for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
        MessageDigest md;
        md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
        md.update(signature.toByteArray());
        String something = new String(Base64.encode(md.digest(), 0));
        //String something = new String(Base64.encodeBytes(md.digest()));
        Log.e("hash key", something);
    }
} catch (NameNotFoundException e1) {
    Log.e("name not found", e1.toString());
} catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
    Log.e("no such an algorithm", e.toString());
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e("exception", e.toString());
}
```